# Angular router outlet problem, model not updates

Tags: angular

I'm creating SPA with angular 6 and I came upon a weird bug, or I'm doing something wrong. 
I have a main component that renders other components inside of it using 
`<router-outlet>`.
When children component is rendered for the first time the data models it uses are correctly updated in view when new data is coming from the backend. 
 
However if I navigate to another route, the children component changes and then come back to previous child component data models doesn't update. Although I can see updated data in the console and debugging scripts that the updated data is present, the view doesn't detect changes.

This is how my app-routing looks like:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
      {
        path: 'creator', component: CreatorComponent, children: [
          {path: 'service', component: CreatorServiceComponent},
          { path: 'device', component: CreatorDeviceComponent },
          { path: 'project', component: CreatorProjectComponent },
          { path: 'build', component: CreatorBuildComponent }
        ]
      },
      {path: 'reporter', component: ReporterComponent},
      {
        path: 'overview', children: [
          {path: 'services', component: ServicesComponent},
          {path: 'devices', component: DevicesComponent },
          {path: 'projects', component: ProjectsComponent },
          {path: 'builds', component: BuildsComponent},
          {path: 'testgroups', component: TestGroupsComponent},
          {path: 'tests', component: TestsComponent}
        ]
      },
      {path: 'logger', component: LoggerComponent}
    ]
  },
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
  {path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent},
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  // otherwise redirect to 404
  {path: '**', redirectTo: '/404'}
];
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
```

And the entry point of my application is HomeComponent:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="outer">
        <app-alert></app-alert>
        <router-outlet>
        </router-outlet>
 </div>
```

This is the component that causes those issues.

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {LoaderService} from '../../_services/loader.service';
import {ServicesManager} from 
'../overview/services/servicesManager.service';
import {Service} from '../../_models/service.model';
import {HubConnection} from '@aspnet/signalr';
import {AlertService} from '../../_services/alert.service';
import {SignalRHandler} from '../../_services/signalR.service';
import {SignalRClient} from '../../_models/SignalRClient';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css'],
  providers: [ServicesManager]
})
export class DashboardComponent extends SignalRClient implements OnInit {

  services: Service[];
  hubConnection: HubConnection;
  signalRHandler: SignalRHandler;

  constructor(signalRHandler: SignalRHandler,
              private loaderServer: LoaderService,
              private serviceManager: ServicesManager,
              private alertService: AlertService
  ) {
    super(signalRHandler);
    this.signalRHandler = signalRHandler;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.serviceManager.getServiceFromDataBase().subscribe(serviceData => {
      this.services = serviceData;
      console.log(this.services);
    }, error => {
      this.alertService.notify({'type': 'error', 'payload': error.statusText});
    });
  }

  acquireHubInstance() {
    this.hubConnection = this.signalRHandler.hubConnection;
    this.hubConnection.on('BroadcastServiceMessage', (data) => {
      console.log(this.services);
      if (this.serviceExists(data)) {
        const index = this.services.findIndex((service) => {
          return service.apiKey === data.apiKey;
        });
        this.services[index] = data;
      } else {
        this.alertService.notify({'type': 'error', 'payload': 'Couldn\'t match any server to update information'});
      }
    });
  }

  private serviceExists(data) {
    return this.services.find((service) => {
      return service.apiKey === data.apiKey;
    });
  }

}
```

Example:
OnInit there are two objects with some information, received from the backend.
Then new data about one object is incoming via web sockets and this data is correctly assigned to the existing object and view correctly updates. 
Then I switch to other component view and go back. 
After I go back there are still the same two objects as during the init and that is correct, but when data from web sockets is received again the same object doesn't get updated. It looks like Component remembers changed objects inside the function `this.hubConnection.on('BroadcastServiceMessage')` that handles WebSockets messages and thus it doesn't update the view which displays globally defined objects in the component.

Comment: I don't see any reasons for that, can you share the stackblitz or anything, so that we can look into the code, are you getting some error in console?

Comment: @nobalG I updated my question.